# setting TTL using timestamp field of record during insertion in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I want to set TTL 30 days from the time field of table record(id,name,time) during insertion. For this I am creating a User Defined Function(UDF) `bigint fun(rTime,cTime)` as

```
CREATE FUNCTION fun(rtime timestamp,ctime timestamp) CALLED ON NULL INPUT  
RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE java as 'return 2592000-((ctime.toTime() -rtime.toTime())/1000);';
```

here,function fun is calculating the time in seconds this data should live. 
2592000 is the time in seconds for 30 days.

Now I am trying to use above function for setting TTL as

```
INSERT INTO record(id,name,time) VALUES (123,'data123','2016-08-08 06:06:00') 
USING TTL fun('2016-08-08 06:06:00',totimestamp(now()));
```

getting error as

> Syntax Exception: ErrorMessage code=2000 ........

Is there any other way to set ttl based on record time field. What is problem with above approach?

Answer (score 1):

Function call is not supported in `USING` clause. 
In you case, your client have to calculate the appropriate `TTL` and pass it in query as second.